# How to split a list of tibbles into their respective tibbles

Tags: r

I want to split a list of tibble into ther respective tibbles. How do I do that? I have 245 tibbles in the list so I can't do that by each one.

Answer (score 2):

Create an example dataset:

```r
library(tibble)
myList <- list("iris_tbl" = as_tibble(iris),
               "cars_tbl" = as_tibble(cars))
```

Answer:

```r
mapply(assign, names(myList), myList, MoreArgs=list(envir = globalenv()))
```

Comment: And how to I split each of those datasets by a column?

Comment: `?split`.  But you *might* want to reconsider an analysis strategy that generates lots and lots of objects in the environments. Using `purrr` functions to iterate over lists of objects, and `group_by` to iterate over categories within a tibble,  is likely to be much more effective in the long run ...

Comment: I need to split all of them at the same time. How do I do that?

Comment: If you create an example of your data (as I did above) and then an example or description of the solution you want that would help!

Comment: or just `list2env(myList,.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @moodymudskipper, running `list2env(myList,.GlobalEnv)`  gives me `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>` and I don't see individual tibbles in the Environment pane.

Comment: Maybe it's not refreshed right away, try `ls()`, you should see the tibbles